# Spam flag disputed but this is overt self-promotion

Tags: discussion, spam

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/274890/2591612) as spam and the flag was returned as disputed. I have quoted the answer here:

> Contact us at Sonatype.com, we have an instance of Nexus that we make
>   available for OSS projects. We would be happy to provide you access to
>   repository space.
>
> Details are here:
>   https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide

[image]
That's the entire answer. I could have flagged it as "Not an Answer" but it is overt self-promotion.

Are spam flags disputed by moderators or the community?

Comment: That isn't spam. It answers the question. I only really use spam flag for questions. If someone seems to be posting the same *spammy looking* answer to multiple questions, than I use an *other* flag and explain to the mod that it looks like he's just spamming and have them take care of it.

Comment: Related: [Guidelines on spam answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228414)

Comment: In general, be lenient about overt self-promotion, and crackdown on covert/occult promotion.

Comment: I agree that it does not answer the question, and promotion for self-service offsite.

Comment: -1 that's no spam nor shameless self-promotion. he did provide an useful answer. it's natural he'll suggest their own product and not someone else's if he thinks it's useful.

Comment: @BenVoigt Why should we be lenient about self-promotion? What if more/all people would do it?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: This is the OP's question from that question: "Can I just deploy my artifacts to my FTP host using mvn deploy, or should I manually deploy and/or setup some things before being able to deploy artifacts?". His answer is self-promotion. It doesn't answer it.

Comment: @VotetoClose: How does it answer the question if the OP's question was "Can I just deploy my artifacts to my FTP host using mvn deploy, or should I manually deploy and/or setup some things before being able to deploy artifacts?". His answer is self-promotion. It doesn't answer it. At a minimum, it should be flagged as "Not an Answer" or "Other". I suppose I should have done that in the first place.

Comment: @Trilarion: How do you develop expertise without creating some conflicts of interest along the way?  The people with the most experience, who know the solutions to the problems, are the ones who have done a project doing exactly what the question is about.  Consider how that answer should have gone: "We at XYZ Co host repositories doing exactly (what you asked about).  While setting them up, we discovered that (Product Z) was the most stable and highest performance option that didn't require a dedicated server.  When you configure it, be sure to ..."

Comment: If an answer is bad, downvote it for being bad.  But don't mark spam for mentioning a commercial or authorship stake in conjunction with an otherwise good answer.  That's just honest disclosure, which we want.

Comment: @BenVoigt My general guideline was that an answer should stand on its own. External references should only support the answer. Therefore promotion should rarely be needed. "Contact us" should never be needed. But yeah I see the point.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I don't even mind some product references that don't disclose affiliation as long as they're not too "pushy". Whether someone says "*I've tried Library XYZ, and you can achieve what you want by doing ...*", or says "*I'm the author of Library XYZ, and you can achieve what you want by doing ...*" doesn't really make a difference, as long as the answer is on topic for that question. (Not quite the use case in this particular question.)

Comment: @BenVoigt: How is it a good answer if it doesn't even attempt to answer it? Did you read the OP's original question? At a minimum it is "Not an Answer" flag capable.

Comment: @staticx: What part of "**in general**, be lenient" did you not understand?  I'm stating a principle for other people who find this meta question and apply it to other answers.  I never said I thought it was a good answer.  I said a spam flag would be wrong.

Comment: @Bruno: I would have a real problem with someone saying "I've tried Library XYZ" or even "Library XYZ can solve your problem if you ..." if in fact the truth was "I'm the author of Library XYZ".  This doesn't mean that only the author's expertise matters; it does mean that affiliation *must* be disclosed.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ok, I thought you were still referring to the post at hand.

Comment: @BenVoigt, maybe..., I think it really depends on the context. My example wasn't great. If there's a good detailed answer that says somewhere at the end "*By the way, there is an example in `http://github-or-similar.../project/example1/`*", I don't mind them not disclosing their potential affiliation (*as long as it's on topic and not saying USE THIS!*), especially for FOSS projects. If it's not *promoting* a product, it doesn't really matter. (The problem with systematic disclosure is that it breaks anonymity and some users can think they can email you about any other problem they have on SO)

Comment: @Bruno: I agree with you, that would be a proper way to promote

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I cleared that spam flag, which left it in a disputed state. While I could see what you were going for, spam flags carry heavy penalties and make the flagged post an audit case, neither of which I felt were justified here.

The question asked for where to host Maven repositories. The user in question provided an answer that indicated that his company (properly disclosing his affiliation) provides free hosting for such projects. This was from a user who had behaved as a good contributor to the site since 2008, has built up 3000 points of reputation, and has not to my eye exhibited a pattern of excessive self-promotion.

Coupled with the fact that at least five people thought that answer useful, I didn't think it warranted being removed as spam. I disputed the flag rather than declining it because I could see what you were intending to say, just didn't feel that deletion was appropriate. Disputed flags don't count against you, it's as if they weren't cast.

Comment: Isn't that whole question a candidate for deletion?  Today it would fall under "requests for an off-site resource", and smells like the answers are less valid now than they were six years ago.

Comment: @BenVoigt It looks like the Meta Effect has collected a couple votes, so far... ;)

Comment: @Andrew: Mine and one other... a very minor meta effect, so far.

Comment: @Ben: Check again. :-) It's only been an hour, and it's commute time in a large part of the US (and Friday night).

Comment: This "heavily penalty" is always mentioned, but what is it?

Comment: @FinalContest - If approved, spam flags [carry an automatic 100-point reputation penalty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/135615) to the poster, add an extra downvote to the post, the posts cannot be undeleted by anyone short of a moderator, the post content is hidden from view (even for those who can see deleted content), and the post is fed into the anti-spam system to potentially block future posts matching a certain pattern. That's what is meant by "heavy penalties" and is why we are conservative in accepting them.

Comment: OK, thanks, I thought something more serious like pre-ban warning or so. 100 reputation is not much and spammers are usually under 100 reputation. The rest is not so big punishment for the spammer.

Comment: @BradLarson: I agree he has in 99.9% of cases been a good StackOverflow user. However, there are some more self promotion posts I have discovered and I will be flagging as "Other". This is not a witchhunt and I have the utmost respect for the user.

Comment: @staticx, to be fair, this [is one of the main companies behind Maven](http://maven.apache.org/team-list.html). So while Maven is strictly speaking an OSS product, it's not entirely distinct from those who work on it in practice, and you wouldn't flag as spam a Microsoft employee pointing to its products in response to a question about their project, would you?

Comment: @Bruno: We still have site standards. This isn't your company support forum. That has been covered by Shog9 on meta.

Comment: @staticx sure, we have site standards, but this isn't at all about company support. The question is about Maven, an OSS tool used by many Java developers. Those can be on topic. Although SO is not a company support forum, it doesn't make sense to exclude contribution by project members themselves (he is a Maven PMC member) or by people who work for companies that support or provide the tools referred to in these questions.

Comment: @Bruno: that's fine.. you stil have to post a valid answer.

Comment: @staticx: Clearly you've misunderstood what "We aren't your company support forum" means.  **It does not mean that employees are unwelcome here**.  It means that questions and answers here must conform to community standards (and the issue is mainly topicality -- nearly all programming questions that could go on a company support forum are welcome here, while none of the recover-my-account or credit-my-bill-for-downtime ones are)

Comment: @BenVoigt: I did not misunderstand it. I stand by the fact that the answer I originally linked to does not attempt to answer the question. If the answerer had attempted to answer it and then stated a promotion, that would be different. But in this case, it just promotes and that's not an answer.

Comment: @staticx, it does offer an alternative solution to the overall problem in the question, though. (This could certainly warrant a downvote, because it's rather outside the constraint range of the question, but it's still a viable solution for someone in a similar situation with slightly different constraints.)

Comment: @Bruno: Seems like a stretch. This is the crux of the OP's question, verbatim: "Can I just deploy my artifacts to my FTP host using mvn deploy, or should I manually deploy and/or setup some things before being able to deploy artifacts? Do I need a tool like Apache Archiva? Note: I only have FTP access to server I want to host the Maven repo on." and the answer that I linked to said, "Just contact us, we'll help." - that's promotion not an answer..

Comment: @staticx, yes, you have a point.

Comment: Looks like he got hit with the spam penalty anyhow :/

Comment: @Will: The answer was converted to a comment.

Comment: @staticx: Nope.  "This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details."  That tends to mean that the answer was marked as spam.

Comment: @Will: Hmm, I can't see that. Not enough rep. I only see what was originally posted as a comment

Comment: @BradLarson: Sorry for badgering you here (and feel free to ignore!) – Could you explain why the spam flag on https://stackoverflow.com/a/48203392/1187415 was disputed? It looks like a clear promotion of a service to me.

Comment: @MartinR - We have reason to believe that their account was compromised, so instead of applying the hard spam flag penalty to their account, we instead cleared the spam flags and contacted them directly. Sorry you didn't get those marked as helpful, but they won't count against you. That was spam, but we want to make sure the user has a chance to recover from having their account exploited.

Answer (score 7):

Drat. This question got closed, by people including me, and it should not have been. The question is asking for a technology solution ("How to I make my ftp site work as a repo"), not for some existing repo resource. So the answer is not a good answer to the question as edited, but it's also not spam, and the meta-effect done it wrong.

Comment: It was reopened.

Comment: There are already another 2 close votes at the moment. It's interesting that questions advertised on Meta somehow seem to get more "negativity". This question had 9 upvotes, no downvotes until it was advertised here. Considering the upvotes on the answers too, it visibly had been of use to some people at least.

Comment: @Bruno: it's also old. Standards have evolved over six years

Comment: @staticx, true but why be negative towards old content that's been fine, seems to have been received mostly with upvotes (until you brought it up here) and have been of some use? You seem to have been a member for just about a year, only with medium activity levels, yet you seem to be quite keen on downvotes, closures, possibly preventing what other members have been fine with for so long.

Comment: @Bruno: I have been a member for much longer. I purposely deleted my account. I was in the Beta. But it doesn't matter. I am well aware of how the site has evolved.

Comment: @staticx, I still can't quite see how this overall negativity, especially when targeted towards old content, can benefit the site. If there's content that's visibly helpful to someone, and about software development, just leave it be. I find that sort of attitude, which seems to have been on the increase in general recently, more annoying than the number of new bad questions we see (although I don't like them either, of course).

Comment: It's not negativity. It showed up in the queue. I am a reviewer like everyone else. I am just following the standards