# Leave open, or vote-to-close: "Can I host Maven on an FTP server..."

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

The post "[Can I host Maven on an FTP server, or should I use something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157463/can-i-host-maven-on-an-ftp-server-or-should-i-use-something-else)" has been closed 3 times and has been re-opened 3 times. It is on it's way to be closed for the 4th time. See the post revision history [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/157463/revisions).

If I recall correctly, it has been closed as (not necessarily in this order):

- Too broad
- A recommendation for a tool

(I did not see the result of the 3rd close vote).

The purpose here is to discuss whether the question should be closed or open. Please give your answer with reasons below.

Comment: You can blame me for starting the meta effect: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266100/spam-flag-disputed-but-this-is-overt-self-promotion

Comment: Perhaps we need a hint that if a question starts "Can I..." it should be rewritten as "How do I..." because the answer to the question "Can I..." is often trivially "yes", but that's not what the user ultimately wants to ask.

Comment: So many times I've wanted to just answer "yes" or "no" then thought better of it.

Comment: @MattBurland "Can you pass me the salt please?"... Frankly, every "*Can I...*" on this site expects at least a short description of how to do what's asked, that's obvious. The small issue here is the "*or use something else*", which makes it sound like a recommendation question. (Note that it wasn't in the initial title.)

Comment: @Bruno We aren't sitting around a dinner table, we're discussing very complex problems. It is important for people asking programming questions to learn to precisely articulate what they're asking for. Learning to communicate effectively is an extremely important skill for programmers, and we aren't doing them any favors if we encourage poor communication. Although the "Can I?" style questions we can infer what they want, it's a dangerous game to play because it's very easy in a programming context to infer that wrong thing.

Comment: @mason Indeed, communication is an extremely important skill, but knowing how not to get stuck at the title because of a slight wording imperfection is equally important. There seems to be a lot of unnecessary drama about this question, which appears to be partly driven by people who seem more interested in being pedantic than in enabling the flow of knowledge between askers and answerers (the lifeblood of this site).

Comment: @Bruno The flow of knowledge doesn't work well when the communication is poorly done. I haven't bothered looking at the aforementioned question, but did want to make my point about not being satisfied with "Can I?" questions.

Answer (score 14):

I think the question is fine. I know the OP writes "*should* I use something else," but from context it really looks like he means "do I *need to* use something else?" He's asking how to do something, not for everyone's opinion.

The only reason I can see to close it is that it seems to fall a little more on the sysadmin side of things, but I think it's on-topic enough (and was asked in 2008 enough) that I don't want to make a binding decision.

Comment: I'd say it's clearly on-topic in terms of subject matter: Maven really is a tool for programmers. (What's debatable is perhaps the tool recommendation aspect, although I agree with your interpretation.)

Comment: @Bill To be clear, should we read your answer as an endorsement that no edits are needed?  No one seems to support closure, I'd like to settle on either "leave open, as is" or "leave open, with edits".

Comment: @BradKoch A few copy edits to remove the ambiguity should be fine. The OP is active, so he can roll back if he doesn't agree.

Answer (score 7):

There's a reason we (I) vote to close - to put a question on hold until it has been edited to remove fundamental problems.  This post is attracting so many poor quality answers and product recommendations because the text is too indirect - there's 4 individual questions, many repeated points, and keywords like "do I need a tool" don't help.  If these issues were corrected, it would be a perfectly fine question worthy of remaining open.

I wasn't ambitious enough to tackle a foreign topic earlier, but this is what I would recommend updating the text to say:

> ## Can I host Maven on an FTP server?
>
> I would like to host a Maven repository for a framework we're working on and its dependencies. I only have FTP access to the server I want to host the Maven repo on; I do not have full control over the host machine.  Can I just deploy my artifacts to my FTP host using mvn deploy, or should I manually deploy and/or set up some things before being able to deploy artifacts?

Comment: "*This post is attracting so many poor quality answers and product recommendations because the text is too indirect*". So many really? There only **1** deleted answer (discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266100/372643) btw), written more or less when the question was asked. It's almost a 6-year old question that initially had 3 answers (now -1) and has had another 2 since. Not really a "poor answer magnet". What it does seem to attract far more, though, is close votes by people who just don't want to leave it alone.

Comment: You're right, 1 comment and 3 answers isn't bad. It doesn't deserve to remain closed. But a few copy edits might help keep the direction of future answers away from mere product recommendations.

Answer (score -9):

#### It should really just be left alone.

The only reason I see for leaving it open is that it was made in 2008. There's no reason to close a question that old. Rules change.

Ignoring that...

I see a few problems when I read the question:

> I would like to host a Maven repository for a framework we're working on and its dependencies. Can I just deploy my artifacts to my FTP host using mvn deploy, or **should I**<sup>1</sup> manually deploy and/or setup some things before being able to deploy artifacts? **Do I need a tool like Apache Archiva?**<sup>2</sup> Note: I only have FTP access to server I want to host the Maven repo on.
>
> The online repository I want to use is not hosted by myself. As I say, I only have FTP access, so if possible, I would like to use that FTP space as a Maven repository. The tools mentioned seem to work when you have full control over the host machine, or at least more than just FTP access since you need to configure the local directories where the repositories will be placed. **Is this possible?**<sup>3</sup>

<sup>1</sup> This phrase is never good.  It allows for subjectivity.
<sup>2</sup> This is asking for a tool *like* Apache Archive, basically a recommendation.
<sup>3</sup> This is too broad of a question. The question as a whole has many factors including two different questions before the actual question, so this is not specific enough.

Overall, it seems *too broad* would be an appropriate close reason since it is about the question as a whole.

Comment: Unfortunately, we need to resolve this.  It's a Famous Question which continues to attract new answers, mostly opinionated product recommendations.

Comment: @BradKoch I really can't see how 3 people could upvote this comment of yours. "*continues to attract new answers*" is just non-sense. After 2008, it has had **2** new answers, one a year ago, one last week, that's it.

Comment: @Brad "Unfortunately, we need to resolve this." Are you implying that my solution would not resolve it? If so, please explain.

Comment: If a problem exists (bad copy) it should be fixed, *it should really just be left alone* doesn't resolve anything.

Comment: @Bruno: I think what he is saying is it has 10,000 views. That's significant.

Comment: @staticx The number of views has an impact on the Famous Question badge indeed, but a question doesn't get better or worse in itself by attracting views. The number of views in itself doesn't justify closure. The only thing it attracts is close votes from some users who want to police the site. Remember those close votes cannot be cancelled by other voters who would vote to keep it open (only possible to re-open, after it has been closed).